# Sin (6°)=6 or sin(6)=6

Tags: trigonometry

For small values of $\theta$, $\sin\theta = \theta$ this must be done in what units radians or degrees

Sin (6°)=6 or sin(6)=6

Comment: theta=\theta surrounded by $

Comment: [Here's a tutorial in MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Of course you can not have $\sin 6 = 6$ since $-1 \leq \sin x \leq +1$.

Answer (score 1):

Not even close. sin(6 radians) is nowhere close to 0.

However, sin(6 degrees) = $\sin(\frac{π}{30})=\sin(0.1047)=0.1045$.

Trigonometric functions are naturally in radians.

Answer (score 0):

By Taylor expansion, we have

$$\sin (x)=x+x^2 (1+\epsilon (x)) $$
thus for very small values of $x $ in RADIANS, we can write
$$\sin (x)\approx x .$$

but
$$x (deg)=180\frac {x (rad)}{\pi}$$
$$\approx 57.2 x(rad)$$

thus the approximation is not correct if $x $ is in degree.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $sin^2(\theta)+cos^2(\theta)=1.$ So $sin^2(\theta) \leq 1.$ So $-1 \leq sin(\theta) \leq 1.$ So neither 6 nor 6º complies what you put. What is true is that $sin(6*(\frac{\pi}{180})) \approx 6*(\frac{\pi}{180})$. For being $6 \leq 15$